# What is a good defrag tool for Windows?

Tags: windows

The built-in defragment tool of Windows is not the best one. I heard that there are a ton of better ones out there - but which one is really good?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use [Jkdefrag](http://www.kessels.com/Jkdefrag/) and read good things about it. Can be used as screensaver as well, have a 64-bit version and is open source.

**Edit :** As of version 4, it's now called [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/).

Comment: +1. I have the commercial Diskeeper but I prefer the Free JkDefrag. I do not have a comparative stats on the two software but I can really tell the difference from the performance of my laptop. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

For a free option at small shops I've been a fan of [Defraggler](http://www.defraggler.com/)

Comment: I also love defraggler!

Answer (score 7):

The necessity of a good 3rd-party defrag tool isn't quite what it used to be, though they're of course still hotly peddled as cure-alls beside generic system cleaners.

The NTFS file system is quite an improvement over FAT32 in this regard, and this TechNet blog article discusses some of Vista's improvements in particular: [Don’t judge a book by its cover – why Windows Vista Defrag is cool](http://blogs.technet.com/filecab/archive/2007/01/26/don-t-judge-a-book-by-its-cover-why-windows-vista-defrag-is-cool.aspx) (nonpartisan I know ;).

For **Vista**:

I'm putting forward that a 3rd party defrag tool is entirely unnecessary. The system scheduled idle defrag (find it in *Task Scheduler->Microsoft->Windows->Defrag*) is more than capable of keeping up with system fragmentation and a manual defrag has little benefit of significance. (Although by all means if you wish to target highly specific performance sensitive problem files and directories with the likes of [contig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx) as [mentioned](https://serverfault.com/questions/1697/what-is-a-good-defrag-tool-for-windows/1876#1876) you should do so.)

I *believe* this is verifiable by simply running the utilities in question and noting that the reported fragmentation is within practical performance levels. (See the article for possible misconceptions.)

Back to the original question: If you merely want to replace this scheduled task with a good defrag tool then my recommendation is for the Windows one already in use, at least on Vista. ;)

---

On earlier versions of Windows I'd vote for [Perfect Disk](http://www.perfectdisk.com/) merely on the result of my past "x vs x", "x better than *", and "x compared to *" Google queries (try the wildcards). For anyone really gung-ho about a substitute for Vista's I'd probably suggest it there as well, or at least the Google searches for comparative research.

Answer (score 3):

[Perfect Disk](http://www.perfectdisk.com/)

I use the [Windows Home Server Edition](http://www.perfectdisk.com/products/home-perfectdisk10-windows-home-server/learn-more) which gives you 10 licenses for all your home computers.

The normal [Home Edition](http://www.perfectdisk.com/products/home-perfectdisk10-home-edition/learn-more) is inexpensive at $30.

Answer (score 3):

[Diskeeper](http://www.diskeeper.com/defrag.aspx) is one of the ones that usually gets mentioned. The Microsoft defrag utility is a limited version (severly) of the Diskeeper disk defragmenter, as per [KB130539](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130539).

Answer (score 2):

[defraggler](http://www.defraggler.com/) has always suited me fine, I've no idea if its any good.  But it's portable and appears to work.

Comment: http://www.defraggler.com/

Answer (score 2):

[JkDefrag](http://www.kessels.com/JkDefrag/), it's open source, fully automatic, can be run as a screen saver or from a Scheduled Task.

> JkDefrag is a disk defragmenter and
>   optimizer for Windows
>   2000/2003/XP/Vista/2008/X64.
>   Completely automatic and very easy to
>   use, fast, low overhead, with several
>   optimization strategies, and can
>   handle floppies, USB disks, memory
>   sticks, and anything else that looks
>   like a disk to Windows. Included are a
>   Windows version, a commandline version
>   (for scheduling by the task scheduler
>   or for use from administrator
>   scripts), a screensaver version, a DLL
>   library (for use from programming
>   languages), versions for Windows X64,
>   and the complete sources.

Answer (score 1):

[Defraggle](http://www.defraggler.com/download) is good stuff

Comment: You linked to Defraggler, which was already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Sysinternals (now bought by Microsoft) made a free command line tool called [Contig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx) that at least have one nice feature in that you can point it to a directory and it will defrag only that and the subdirectories but not the rest of the disk. I have no experience with the other programs mentioned in the other answers. The performance hit when running contig is noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

My site just deployed '[PerfectDisk](http://www.perfectdisk.com/)'.  It looks to be a good tool and can be centrally managed and deployed to the Desktops.  I just ran a few defrags with it and it did improve speed and has a detailed interface letting you know what's going on.

-JFV

Answer (score 1):

[IOBit SmartDefrag](http://www.iobit.com/iobitsmartdefrag.html) is fantastic -- we used to shell out for the cadillac version of Diskeeper for our servers, but now we just  use SmartDefrag.  It's got all the functionality in the sfotware we were paying for, and even has a feature that optimizes the placement of more frequently used files.

Answer (score 1):

Disk Keeper is the best defrag util that you can pay for according to many reviews...

Answer (score 1):

i've tried Diskeeper, O&O Defrag and the rest. i find **PerfectDisk** to be the best.

It actually defragments my hard drive, rather than complaining when there isn't 20% free space. It also *doesn't* try to be an enterprise defragmenter, or a defragment-while-you-work product - taking up computer resources and causing I/O delays while i'm working or playing.

i schedule it to run at 1:00 AM. It runs at 1:00 AM, and then stops running.

Comment: Based on your recommendation I just tried PerfectDisk and am very impressed. I'll be switching over to it immediately on all my machines.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the open source [UltraDefrag](http://ultradefrag.sourceforge.net/). It has boot time defragmentation, a feature implemented by the author at my request.

Answer (score 1):

[O&O Defrag](http://www.oo-software.com/home/en/products/oodefrag/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Magical Defrag](http://www.ashampoo.com/frontend/products/php/product.php?idstring=0144), It is pay software at about $20 depending on where u come from but it does a good thorough job.

Answer (score 0):

I like defraggler from Piriform.

Answer (score 0):

I recommened iobit's Smart Defrag

Answer (score 0):

I've found it does a better job than the built-in defragger (Diskeeper Lite in disguise), but so far the best defragger I've used has been O&O Defrag Professional. (I do not work for them.)

Answer (score 0):

I've used IOBit Smart Defrag without any problems.  As you mentioned, I like how it defrags in the background.  (I too do not work for them)

Answer (score 0):

I'd second PerfectDisk as my defragger of choice. Newer versions also have "enterprise defrag" options like particular defrag strategies for specific environments (eg: VMWare virtual machines & SQL)