# Decent Defrag tool for windows

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm looking for a decent defrag tool for windows server 2008 r2, I'm not sure if the answers in [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/1697/what-is-a-good-defrag-tool-for-windows) are still current. Care to share what you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Auslogics Disk Defrag](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/disk-defrag/), works well for me. Able to defrag and defrag+optimize disks, also supports moving system files to the start of the disk.

Comment: Auslogics wins over Defraggler, if you ask me.

Better overall performance, better options, possibility to move system files to the start of the disk, automatic shutdown and similar options :)

Install apps from ninite.com: they are the best.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used jkdefrag which morphed into [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/).

Works very well, has a command line version and includes a handful of stock scripts that should handle most of your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I've got [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler) from the piriform guys (also do CCleaner and Recuva) for the occasional time I do want to do a defrag. Does the job well enough, for free, and supports HTFS and FAT32 partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use defraggler for any servers I manage. Its simple and it works. Never had any problems.

However it doesn't have some features which I'd like to see. Having said that neither do any of the other free ones.

It is convenient to have large and high activity files (like vhd  or sql db, sql logs, normal log files)  placed so that there is a space for expansion after the file. None of the tools I've tried allow this.

On disks with really big files I've found that all of the free tools move the big files around when they are not fragmented - never understood why. With small files you don't really care too much but shifting several 50gb files every day is a bit much.

I would imagine that diskkeeper would perform much better on larger systems but I haven't tried it.